# Notepad++ Convert single column of csv data into multiple-value rows

Tags: notepad++

Problem: File with 10,000 records, csv (comma separated)
Sample Data:

one,
two,
three,
four,
five,
six,
I need to create groups of rows e.g.
one, two, 
three, four,
five, six

How can I accomplish this in Notepad++ ?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very good CSV if every comma separated value is on a new line also. Anyway I don't know if there would be a way to do this with Notepad++. It seems like a programmer could whip something up for this easily though. Would you want to group them after every 6 values (make a new line)? I'd also reword the question title, maybe change "multiple rows" to "multiple-value rows".

Comment: Yes, group them after every 10 values (make a new line)

Answer (score 1):

You can search and replace by regular expression.

What you have is a file with:
`<value>,\r\n<value>,\r\n<value>,\r\n`

You want to create a regular expression which matches 2 values and removes the new line in between.

Go to search and replace (shortcut: control+H) and enter the following:

- find: `(.*)\,\r\n(.*)\,\r\n`
- replace: `\1, \2,\r\n`

Make sure search mode is `regular expression` and that `. matches newline` option is not checked. Press the "replace all" button and your file should be formatted.

NOTE: If your file is not following the windows style end of line, and instead uses a linux style end of line, replace `\r\n` with `\n` in the examples above.